# Strange Parent motion.missing dope sheet

Tags: animation, parent, dopesheet

[Teddy Bear 5Walk3.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16asWU638jbP_kql-sJRsoTvddt3wyGAP)

[Teddy Bear 5Walk3.blend1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FvvJKrwS16Ip9ZFfncjOMgBT_QkMXPHX)

I'm trying to get this teddy bear to look around, get up and walk away. I see two problems: the EYE & NOSE rotate around the face as it's moving and I can't find any keyframes in the dope sheet. Any Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: And this is why the blender community is so great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your eyes and nose are not controlled by any bone. What you should do is:

- Select your armature, in *Pose* mode select all and bring back your bones to their rest pose with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>. By the way it would be better if, by default, in rest pose, you armature stood up, and the character's mesh as well, you could correct this in *Edit* mode for both the objects but it's another topic.

[image]

- Select your eyes and nose, <kbd>Shift</kbd> select your body and join. Go in *Edit* mode, move your eyes and nose where they are supposed to be (and delete the double eyes and nose you've created).

[image]

- Your eyes and nose are still not controlled by any bone, select them in *Edi*t mode. As it's the HeadBone that is supposed to control them, go in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data > Vertex Groups*, select the HeadBone group and click on the *Assign* button. Now eyes and nose should follow.

[image]